# Получение списка экземпляров класса

Tags: python, классы

Существует некоторый класс, подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу достать объект класса по индексу? Например, чтобы пользователь ввел число(это и было бы индексом)

```
class Goom(object):
    a = []

    def __init__(self, name, seats, jump):
        """Инициализация"""
        self.name = name
        self.seats = seats
        self.jump = jump
        self.a.append(self)
```

Например вот объекты:

```
my_goom1 = Goom("Лил", "1", "Нет")
my_goom2 = Goom("Мак", "1", "Есть")
my_goom3 = Goom("Ной", "1", "Есть")
```

Может через метод **getitem**?

```
    @classmethod
    def __getitem__(cls):
        """Показывает выбранный объект"""
        num = int(input('Введите число: ')
        print(cls.a[num])
```

Как я могу потом вызвать эту функцию? Спасибо большое за любые советы

Comment: Что вы понимаете под фразой объект класса?  В смысле свойство экземпляра класса? Они не упорядочены, у них нет индекса. Можно только по называнию свойства.

Comment: `print(Goom.a[0])`?

Comment: Я бы хотел вывести например, вот это: "Лил", "1", "Нет" (если индекс 0)В списке <a> находятся элементы my_goom1...

Comment: Все равно не понял) Индекс чего 0?)

Comment: У меня есть список <a> в нем хранятся объекты (my_goom1, my_goom2, my_goom3) можно ли по индексу этого списка (а) вывести всё что находится например в my_goom1?

Comment: Непонятно при этом зачем вам список внутри самого объекта

Comment: Создать словарь или список с экземплярами класса и обращаться к ним по ключу или по идексу, тут уж как удобней

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через `@classmethod` нет возможности переопределить метод `__getitem__` класса. При попытке обращения через квадратный скобки будет возникать ошибка `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`.

**Нерабочий пример:**

```
class Goom(object):
    items = []
 
    def __init__(self, name, seats, jump):
        """Инициализация"""
        self.name = name
        self.seats = seats
        self.jump = jump
        Goom.items.append(self)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.name, self.seats, self.jump)
 
    @classmethod
    def __getitem__(cls, index):
        return cls.item[index]
 
 
my_goom1 = Goom("Лил", "1", "Нет")
my_goom2 = Goom("Мак", "1", "Есть")
my_goom3 = Goom("Ной", "1", "Есть")
 
print(Goom[0])
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "./prog.py", line 24, in <module>
# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Как вариант, можно обращаться через само поле со списком объектов:

```
class Goom(object):
    items = []

    def __init__(self, name, seats, jump):
        """Инициализация"""
        self.name = name
        self.seats = seats
        self.jump = jump
        Goom.items.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.name, self.seats, self.jump)


my_goom1 = Goom("Лил", "1", "Нет")
my_goom2 = Goom("Мак", "1", "Есть")
my_goom3 = Goom("Ной", "1", "Есть")

print(Goom.items[0])
```

Comment: А, я понял зачем этот список нужен. Это хитрый прием, чтобы его каждый раз руками не класть в список при создании нового объекта класса?

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, всё поучилось

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то у вас есть список объектов класса `Goom`?  Например

```py
my_goom1 = Goom("Лил", "1", "Нет")
my_goom2 = Goom("Мак", "1", "Есть")
my_goom3 = Goom("Ной", "1", "Есть")

goom_list = [my_goom1, my_goom2, my_goom3]
```

И вы хотите взять любой объект из этого списка по индексу и вывести его свойства через print.

Не уверен, что вопрос был именно в этом, но если я его правильно понял, то вы можете переопределить метод `__str__` в определении класса.

```py
class Goom(object):
    def __init__(self, name, seats, jump):
        self.name = name
        self.seats = seats
        self.jump = jump

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, {self.seats}, {self.jump}'
```

А потом просто печатать сам объект. В этом случае функция `print` напечатает то, что возвращает метод `__str__`, переданного в нее объекта. Вместо `__str__` можно переопределить также метод `__repr__`.

```py
print(goom_list[0])
```

Comment: Да, вопрос был именно в этом, могу ли я восподьзоваться уже созданным списком <a>? А не создавать новый? Через cls?

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу @insolor

Перегрузить `__getitem__` класса `Goom` возможно, но нужно это делать не в самом классе `Goom`, а в его метаклассе.

```
class Subscriptable(type):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self.items[k]

class Goom(metaclass=Subscriptable):
    items = []

    def __init__(self, name, seats, jump):
        """Инициализация"""
        self.name = name
        self.seats = seats
        self.jump = jump
        Goom.items.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.name, self.seats, self.jump)

my_goom1 = Goom("Лил", "1", "Нет")
my_goom2 = Goom("Мак", "1", "Есть")
my_goom3 = Goom("Ной", "1", "Есть")

print(Goom[0]) # Лил 1 Нет
```